# Prevent Word from automatically copying template to the templates folder

Tags: templates, ms-word

I have a Microsoft Word Macro-enabled Template on a removable drive (please don't tell me that it's not recommended, that's not the question here). And Word keeps on copying the template to the default templates folder (`C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`) automatically, and Word automatically attaches its attached documents to the copied template in the templates folder.

I couldn't find out exactly when it's happening, it definitely doesn't happen **every time** I open or save the template or one of its attached documents, but it keeps on happening.

I tried denying permission for *SYSTEM* to write to the templates folder (via right click>properties>security), since I thought that the *system* might be the troublemaker. But it didn't solved the problem.

I also tried denying permission for myself, but that prevented me from saving edits to the Normal Template.